# PHP, Laravel Controller: Maximum number of methods in a class

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a project where a single class will have lots of methods,
For now the number of methods are 145*5=725, But it will increase with time and needs.

My question is, Is it a bad practice and will it kill performance ?

Comment: Try to reuse method by sending parameter or anything if it is possible.Rather if it is really need to write so many method that's not impact a huge in performance,but it will better keep clean your classes

Comment: These methods are for database CRUD... These can't be reuse, Because the fields are different of the tables.

Comment: then create a method for save and pass the method an array where have field,value and another parameter for table name.In that way you don't need to make multiple method for multiple save,you can save anything by access a single method,and that's the way of reuse

Comment: Listen to @ImtiazPabel. If you give an example of your methods I'm sure we can help to reduce them. 725 methods might not kill performance, but are definitely unreadable. If you have so many methods separate them into different classes

Comment: If you ask someone else to update a controller with 725 methods and he tries to stab you with a spoon don't be surprised

Comment: @BojanKogoj, Hahaha, Okay i am not gonna do that things that way...

Comment: @ImtiazPabel, Yeah that make sense ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad practice and you should avoid this, but on the other hand Laravel `Model` class has 219 methods and 3530 lines of code, for example.

I don't think it will kill perfomance, but if you have a chance to organize those methods better, do it.